# How to handle errors when making a call to app insights?

Tags: error-handling, azure-application-insights, telemetry

My web app is integrated with App Insights for telemetry purposes.
My question is this:

If I have my app insights configured incorrectly, i will get an error.
Should this error break the UI, or gracefully let the user know of the error, or should it just be silent/ignore it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the type of application, end users etc.

**Type of application** - If this is going to be a public facing application, I don't think you would want the end users to know that there was an error with instrumentation. A regular check of the data being collected could help you understand if AppInsights is not configured correctly.

**End users** - If the end users are internal to your organization/team, the error information on UI could be considered for faster diagnosis.

Depending on the Framework/platform being used for the application, you could enable it using [Auto-Instrumentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview) which does not require a lot of configuration update to enable AppInsights. The chance of error here would be minimal.

However, if you are going with the [SDK method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?tabs=net#how-do-i-instrument-an-application), you could check the AppInsights logs, dashboards after a few minutes of hosting the application, to ensure that the data is flowing in.